# What is the default timeout set in forward-request

Tags: azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

In the official documentation, it is set to None. What does None means?

[image]

Comment: 300 seconds (5 mins)

Comment: @MohamadHaidar max is 240 so how can default be 300? I guess its 30 sec

Comment: 240 is the loadbalancer default tcp timeout not the http request default timeout and that is why they mention that the request may not get respected after waiting for a response for 240 seconds. At the end, apim is an app deployed to a vm behind a loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the default timeout in forward-request set to none is not the `no timeout`.

As Specified in the same official documentation, `forward-request` is a root element and the required in the operation level policy.

Any value greater than `240` seconds won't be reliable and it can timeout within the range of `0` to `240` seconds, and the fix of timeout issue can be like changing the implementation a bit if that's in your control based on the number of requests forwarded by APIM gateway or backend instances or due to proxy response time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Documentation shows 300 default but max is 240 seconds. I got timeout after 30 second so I believe it is a mistake in docs. Default should be 30 seconds.